# Handle VPN Connections via AppleScript

Tags: if-statement, applescript, vpn

In order to keep my VPN connection active, i wrote this little applescript:

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell network preferences
    connect service "VPNServiceNameIConfigured"
  end tell
end tell
```

This script works fine!
I wrote myself a lauchdeamon .plist to call the script on StartUp, WakeUp and every 5 seconds. This means, that every time my vpnconnection breaks, it will be automatically reconnected (if possible) every 5 seconds.

This part works fine but i want to improve it a little. I want to use a if-case like

```
if network preferences service "VPNServiceNameIConfigured" is not connected
  connect it
else do nothing
```

Is there a way to do that? If so i am very happy about an example or good documentation using applescript for handling system events.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The place to look for that information is in the Dictionary for System Events. You can open any dictionary using “Open Dictionary…" in AppleScript Editor’s File menu.

You don’t give enough information to write exact code; for example, does your VPNServiceNameIConfigured service contain any configurations?

If you can get a configuration, you should be able to check the “connected” of that configuration. Something like:

```
if connected of current configuration of service VPNServiceNameIConfigured is false then
    connect it
end if
```

Depending on your setup, you might also be able to check the “active” boolean of service VPNServiceNameIConfigured. Here’s a simple test script that works on my setup to check that my WiFi is active:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell network preferences
        set myConnection to location "Automatic"
        --get name of every service of myConnection
        set myService to service "Wi-FI" of myConnection
        --get properties of myConnection
        if active of myService is false then
            display dialog "Need to reconnect"
        end if
    end tell
end tell
```

The “connected” boolean is only available on a configuration, however, and that may be your more reliable option, if your service contains a configuration.

Comment: thank you Jerry Stratton, i am not sure what you mean by configuration - sorry. I created a VPNConnection using the network manager  and the guide on hide.io. So now at my network manager there is right under the common WLAN entry, my HideIO entry where, when i click on it, i can connect or disconnect to the configured VPN. I will try to figure out what your example is like and report back! Thank you very much!

Comment: If you get the properties of your service, it should tell you if there are is a current configuration attached to it. In your case, “get properties of service "VPNServiceNameIConfigured"”.